# How do I change the translateX() value of the transform property using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, css

I want to grab the translateX() value of the transform property and take away -400px to it each time my onDocumentMouseScroll event is fired. I'm new to JavaScript and unsure of how to do this, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
var bg = document.querySelector('section.bg-type');
```

```
function moveBackground() {
  if (bg.style.transform.translateX != -1600) {
    bg.style.transform = "translateX(" + (-400) + "px)";
  }
};
```

```
function onDocumentMouseScroll(event) {
  console.log(event);

  if (Date.now() - lastMouseWheelStep > 600) {

    lastMouseWheelStep = Date.now();

    var delta = event.detail || -event.wheelDelta;
    if (delta > 0) {
      navigateNext();
      addOnScroll();
      moveBackground();


    } else if (delta < 0) {
      navigatePrev();
    }

  }

}
```

When the user scrolls 'transform: translateX(-400px)' property and value are added to the CSS for.bg-type, then -400 is taken away from the on each scroll after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about storing the last translateX value and updating it?

```
let lastTranslateX = 0;

function moveBackground() {
  if (bg.style.transform.translateX != -1600) {
    lastTranslateX -= 400;
    bg.style.transform = "translateX(" + (lastTranslateX) + "px)";
  }
};
```

EDIT: Removed `let` before `lastTranslateX -= 400` as suggested by Temani Afif in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but that's not working for me. I think the problem is in the  "if (bg.style.transform.translateX != -1600)". I not sure if that's grabbing the translateX() value. All your other code makes sense as far as I'm concerned though.

Comment: I'm getting an "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token -=" on the "let lastTranslateX -= 400;" in the console BTW.

Comment: @SeanK you need to remove `let` inside the if, you are redefining the variable again which is wrong

Comment: Temani the kindness of strangers never ceases to amaze me, it worked! You are a true hero amongst humans!